# TCheckListBox get count checked item

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5, tchecklistbox

I have a simple question. How to get the count of checked item in CheckBoxListBox without using a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TCheckListBox` does not provide the option that you are looking for.  A loop through its `Checked[]` property is required.

If you were using Delphi, you could create a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) to hide that loop.  But class helpers are not available in C++.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function like this.

```
function GetCheckedCount(CH:TCheckListBox):Integer;
var I:Integer;
begin
   Result := 0;
    for i := 0 to ch.Items.Count - 1 do
      if ch.Checked[i] then inc(result);
end;
```

Also, SelCount is the number of **"selected"** items when MultiSelect is true ,Not number of **"Checked"** items

Comment: That looks like a loop to me :).

A loop could be avoided by updating a global count variable in the TCheckListBox.OnClickCheck event.

Good point about the meaning of SelCount, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can [*] do the following:

```
TCustomMultiSelectListControl(TheBox).MultiSelect := True;
```

and then SelCount works:

```
CountOfCheckedItems := TheBox.SelCount;
```

Isn't the equivalent possible in C++?

[*] *Although it causes other problems.*

Comment: Actually, forget that - it doesn't even always return the correct count.

Comment: SelCount is the number of selected(Not checked ) items in the Listbox when MultiSelect is true.
It will not work this question case